# JQuery Mobile list elements overly sensitive to taps

Tags: jquery-mobile, tap

I've noticed that when I have long list elements in JQuery Mobile and I try to scroll them, I accidentally select an element.  Overall the act of scrolling tends to get confused with tapping.

I did some comparison to a native iOS list and here is the difference:

In JQueryMobile, as long as you do a MouseDown and MouseUp on an element, it is considered a click.  It doesn't matter if you've scrolled inbetween the events.

In iOS, if you do a MouseDown on an element and then scroll at all, the MouseDown is effectively canceled.  This allows you to tap on something, scroll the page up and release without it being considered a click.

Has anyone noticed this and/or developed a patch for it?  If not, any suggestions on a fix?

Comment: Have you tried to attach the TAP event instead of CLICK?

Comment: So far I haven't had to attach any events - it is all native to JQuery Mobile.  (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html)

Comment: I know how a list works, however you haven't specified if you were using a read-only list attaching an event or a list with <a>s inside.

Comment: Sorry - was using a list with <a> tags inside.  Never thought about not doing that, however.  Are you suggesting I just do <li> elements with unique IDs and attach my own event handler for each element?  Like $("#list-element-123").live('tap',function(event) { // Do Something } ?